# How to drop a column when it has more missing values than another column in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to drop a column when it has more missingness than the other column. Here is a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 col.x = c(44,55,66,NA,NA),
                 col.y = c(44,NA,66,NA,NA))

> df
  id col.x col.y
1  1    44    44
2  2    55    NA
3  3    66    66
4  4    NA    NA
5  5    NA    NA
```

In this case, `col.y` has more missing values so I need to drop `col.y`. How can I get the desired dataset below?

```
   > df
      id col.x 
    1  1    44    
    2  2    55    
    3  3    66    
    4  4    NA    
    5  5    NA
```

Comment: Can we assume that they are the same where none of them is NA?

Comment: Yes. that assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns only differ with respect to their missing values, we can use `coalesce()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  col.x = c(44, 55, 66, NA, NA),
  col.y = c(44, NA, 66, NA, NA)
)

df |> 
  mutate(col = coalesce(col.x, col.y), .keep = "unused")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>      id   col
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    44
#> 2     2    55
#> 3     3    66
#> 4     4    NA
#> 5     5    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This coalesces (i.e. merges) the columns, rather than drops one. The data frame you end up with happens to be the same in this case, but I would say that assuming that will always be the case is optimistic.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing this out. Perhaps still of value to the person who asked?

Comment: merging the two columns would do the job too since these two columns were based on the two merging procedure. I wanted to keep the most populated column while not losing any information.

Answer (score 3):

Excluding the column with max `NA`s

```
df[,-which.max(colSums(is.na(df)))]
  id col.x
1  1    44
2  2    55
3  3    66
4  4    NA
5  5    NA
```

Use `drop=F` if you want to make sure you get a `data.frame` no matter how many columns you remove, e.g. `df[,1,drop=F]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer using Tidyverse syntax (arguably far less concise than the base R approach suggested by @Andre Wildberg):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  col.x = c(44, 55, 66, NA, NA),
  col.y = c(44, NA, 66, NA, NA)
)

max_col <- df |> 
  summarise(across(starts_with("col"), \(x) sum(is.na(x)))) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "column", values_to = "value") |> 
  slice_min(value) |> 
  pull(column)

df |> select(id, all_of(max_col))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>      id col.x
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    44
#> 2     2    55
#> 3     3    66
#> 4     4    NA
#> 5     5    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>